# Things don't work after performing Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have the following problem: I have a ViewController with an UIScrollView and an UICollectionView in it. When I launch the App directly at this View Controller, everything works fine. When I call the ViewController, from another ViewController (here it is a Google Maps SDK Map), the ViewController loads, but when I try to scroll I get this Message, and the App stops:

```
*** -[TheSecondViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16ef3890
```

Here is some more code:
Calling the view:

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {

     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OpenSecondView" sender:self];

}
```

viewDidLoad in the secondView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if (IS_IPHONE5) {

        self.scrollV.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
        NSLog(@"Das Geraet ist ein iPhone 5 / iPhone 5S");

    } else {

        self.scrollV.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        NSLog(@"Das Geraet ist ein iPhone 4 / iPhone 4S");

    }

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollV];

    [scrollV setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollV setDelegate:self];
    [scrollV setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 833)];
    [collectionV setScrollEnabled:NO];

    activityInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;

    [activityInd startAnimating];

    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

}
```

Comment: Pls Provide some more details and source code

Comment: Provide some source code from the viewDidLoad of the SecondViewController

Comment: Looks like some of your properties is missing strong reference. Please post some more info.

Comment: I changed two properties from weak to strong. Now I get a EXC_BREAKPOINT...

Comment: Maybe you could add that code to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that you have just loaded the secondViewController, it looks like your secondViewController is not allocated properly(rather than being deallocated). Try using segues that are created in storyboard and calling those segues with code, and/or using strong instead of weak references to your view

Comment: I solved the problem now. I changed some properties and deleted the simulators data. Now it works...